# git remote push : Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, remote-server

I have been trying to set up a staging machine to run project at home (rails application).

```
# Remote machine connection
REPLOGIN=joel
REPADDRESS=192.168.2.100
REPLOCATION=/Users/joel/Projects/bio_watts #Repo location
REPNAME=biowatts

# Copy the repo to the server
echo "Copying the git repo to the server $REPADDRESS"
echo "repname:$REPNAME"
TEMPREP="$REPNAME.git"
echo "$TEMPREP"
git clone --bare .git $TEMPREP
scp -r $TEMPREP $REPLOGIN@$REPADDRESS:$REPLOCATION/

# Set up the origin for the project
#echo "Linking current repository to remote repository"
git remote add imac $REPLOGIN@$REPADDRESS:$REPLOCATION/$REPNAME.git/
```

All this worked fine

```
$git remote
imac   <== this is my remote machine
```

When I try to git push to this machine I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I know there is something about SSH ... but I don't understand what I need to do on my local and on my remote machines (Mac OS X Lion).

Can someone help?

Cheers,

Joel

NEXT QUESTION:

On my remote machine I do find my cloned biowatts.git file ... but I don't see the project files (rails app) ... how does it work?

My intent is to git push to my imac and run my app there (thin start) ???

Do I need to copy my file manually? I assumed that the git clone would copy every I needed ...

Comment: Can you connect via SSH "normally" to this machine? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote git server should know your machine via your iMac's public ssh key and should have a config somewhere allowing you to push (write rights).

Comment: I found a some ideas here http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html and it seems to work fine. I did this: scp id_rsa.pub joel@192.168.2.100:./id_rsa.pub and then I created a authorized_keys on the remote machine in .ssh and it works I managed to push. Only now I have my project.git file on the remote but I don't have the files ... I am a little new to this, I don't know what to do next to be able to see my files and start my server on the remote machine

Comment: Usually you go through a git-server as a middleman. That means you either have your Github account as a middleman or a separate git user on your remote server that runs something like Gitosis. From your user on your server that runs your app, you clone the files from the Gitrepo (that is usually the deployment process). To get your files out of your project.git, you could git clone project.git into your directory of choice to "unpack" it.

Comment: do u mean there is a  git-server command I can run so I can the master branch files on my remote? Sorry I am really new to this

Comment: So a 'git clone project.git' would unpack ... then I suppose I need to run another git add remote on my dev env right? and remove project.git (?) I'll read a little more about Gitosis. Thanks Tim

Comment: That's ok. If you have the privileges, make a user on your server called "git" and install Gitosis in there (see http://fclose.com/b/linux/1432/setting-up-git-server-using-gitosis/), then add your iMac's SSH Key to git's authorized keys. See also this post for more info http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/05/dead-simple-rails-deployment/

Answer (score 1):

That remote machine needs to know about your ssh keys.

You need to generate a key locally (if you don't have one) and then add the public key to the remote server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

You can follow the GitHub tutorial on setting up keys (if you don't already have them set up).

http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/

Instead of Step 4. Add your SSH key to GitHub, you'll need to add your key to the authorized_keys file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, for those of you encountering this in assembla specifically, the solution is to copy your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the assembla profile. [This post gives step by step instructions.](http://www.johnvarghese.com/permission-denied-publickeykeyboard-interactive/)

Comment: Unfortunately that link is dead :(